# Dependency Tree Error while installing [react-top-loading-bar]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, dependencies

**I am getting this type of error while installing the different packages using npm. I don't want to install those packages by doing --force or anything else. This is critical as it is I am in between development of my project. Does anyone help me to resolve this issue?**

node --version - 16.16.0
npm --version - 8.11.0

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: nims@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR! react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-top-loading-bar@2.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-top-loading-bar

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/25034

Answer (score -1):

it occurs due to npm v7 and it can be solved by many ways but if you don't want to use --force or the other ,just simply type this in to your terminal ;

```
npm install -g npm@6
```

i hope it helps...

Comment: If you know the issue "can be solved by many ways", then please detail 1 or more of those ways first, before suggesting a lazy workaround.

Comment: The issue is with the version of npm-7 and every other person is facing this issue that is why I have recommended using that way and its the perfect solution for the problem, not a lazy workaround ..chill bro...easy

Comment: Downgrading an app by a full version number is a pretty extreme workaround for any issue. If there are known solutions, that makes downgrading a lazy way out. There is nothing wrong with choosing lazy workarounds; only so much time in a day. But you should let OP make that choice. Present the real solution that you claim to know about, and then say "but I would probably just do this instead."